# Развернуть таблицу сотрудников, чтобы запрос составил список строк

Tags: sql

Всем доброго времени, есть такое задание - Unpivot employee table so that the query will make list of rows (with row id) from list of columns - в переводе звучит так - Развернуть таблицу сотрудников, чтобы запрос составил список строк (с идентификатором строки) из списка столбцов. Есть такие данные

Я так понимаю что это ожидаемый результат

```
    EMPNO   VALUE       VALUE_ID
    000010  CHRISTINE   10
    000010  HAAS        20
    000010  I           30
    000010  A00         40
    000010  3978        50
    000020  MICHAEL     10
    000020  THOMPSON    20
    ...         


VALUE_ID mapping:
10  FIRSTNME
20  LASTNAME
30  MIDINIT
40  WORKDEPT
50  PHON
```

Походу дело в том, что нужно сделать столбец VALUE_ID к которому привязать empno(это айди сотрудника), CHRISTINE (это firstnme), HAAS (это lastnme), I (это какой то midinit), A00 (это workdept)...далее идет следующий человек и так до конца...
Я не понимаю что здесь надо сделать и как должен выглядеть код запроса

Т.е. при вводе этого запроса

```
SELECT empno, firstnme, lastname, midinit, workdept, phoneno
FROM employee
```

Я получаю:

```
EMPNO   FIRSTNME   LASTNAME   MIDINIT   WORKDEPT   PHONENO
00010   cristinie  haas       i         a00        3978
00020   michael    thompson   l         b01        3476
и так далее
```

А мне в итоге нужно получить

```
EMPNO(айди человека)   VALUE(combo-значение)  VALUE_ID(его нет в таблице)
000010                CHRISTINE        10
000010                HAAS             20
000010                I                30
000010                A00              40
000010                3978             50
000020                MICHAEL          10
000020                THOMPSON         20
```

Исходя из моей логики и прочитанного материала запрос должен выглядеть как то так(но это не точно) или я где то запутался

```
SELECT empno, combo, values_id
FROM employee, TABLE(values(frirstnme, '10'), (lastname, '20'), (midinit, '30'), (workdept, '40'), (phoneno, '50')) AS tab(combo, values_id)
ORDER BY empno, values_id
```

В ОБЩЕМ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ - он правильный, изначально лишние скобки поставил
Всем спасибо кто обратил внимание

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169), особе внимание пунктам 5 и 3.

Comment: @Akina вроде немного подправил

Comment: Пункт 5 проигнорирован - а зря... какой смысл показывать, что надо получить, если неизвестно, из чего это надо получить?

Comment: @Akina постарался написать запрос приблизительный (продублировал в основном вопросе) - SELECT empno, combo, values_id
FROM employee, TABLE(values((frirstnme, '10'), (lastname, '20'), (midinit, '30'), (workdept, '40'), (phoneno, '50'))) AS tab(combo, values_id)
ORDER BY empno

Comment: В общем все получилось, забыл лишние скобки убрать изначально. Всем спасибо кто обратил внимание на мою проблему